# Is there any way to calculate the white distance from the image using python opencv

Tags: python-3.x, image, opencv, image-processing

**As you can see in the image, the size of the image is 2000*2000. We have to find the distance of the image from all the 4 coordinates. I am trying with opencv contours but on some other image it is not working.**

```
image = cv2.imread(image_full_path)
ori_h, ori_w, _ = image.shape
print("Original height, width-->", ori_h, ori_w)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  # grayscale
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 150, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)  # threshold
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_CROSS, (3, 3))
dilated = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations=13)  # dilate
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(dilated, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)  # get contours

idx = 0
# for each contour found, draw a rectangle around it on original image
# print('length', len(contours))
for contour in contours:
    idx += 1

    # get rectangle bounding contour
    [x, y, w, h] = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
    remaining_height_bottom = ori_h - (y + h)
    remaining_width_right_side = ori_w - (x + w)

    print("Upper Height, Right Width-->", y, x)
    print("Bottom Height, Left Width-->", remaining_height_bottom, remaining_width_right_side)
    print("Image Height, Image Width-->", h, w)
```

[image: Image size is 2000 * 2000]

Thanks in advance.If anyone thinks that the way of asking questions is wrong please ignore. I really need help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: On what image your logic is not working? please post it and also the code segment you are using to detect the distance.

Comment: @Community Please find the code

Comment: @PrashantMaurya Basically I need to calculate the distance and white space of the image for all the coordinates

Comment: "is not working" - what does it mean? Provide incorrect results. If there is only one image it is good to find the bigest contour.

Comment: @Hihikomori not working it means i have 200 images where i need to calculate distance. It only works for some images.

Comment: What happens for others? Incorrect results? Process failure? It is important to know something about incorrect results to propose a fix.

Comment: Don't worry, it is quite normal that it does not work with all images.

Comment: Original height, width--> 2000 2000
Upper Height, Right Width--> 1738 1748
Bottom Height, Left Width--> 235 225
Image Height, Image Width--> 27 27
Upper Height, Right Width--> 1646 1217
Bottom Height, Left Width--> 324 754
Image Height, Image Width--> 30 29
Upper Height, Right Width--> 1221 582
Bottom Height, Left Width--> 751 1385
Image Height, Image Width--> 28 33
Upper Height, Right Width--> 1111 1154
Bottom Height, Left Width--> 862 819
Image Height, Image Width--> 27 27
Upper Height, Right Width--> 0 0
Bottom Height, Left Width--> 0 0
Image Height, Image Width--> 2000 2000

Comment: @Hihikomori for other image it showing like that. please find above comment.

Comment: More then one contour were detected. Is there one correct among them. If it is, it must be that is not the contour of the whole image, but probably the contour with biggest area.

Comment: @Hihikomori yes contour is the largest area but we only need to calculate image distance from all vertices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Please find the code below it working for me**

```
img = cv2.imread(file_full_path) # Read in the image and convert to grayscale
ori_h, ori_w, _ = img.shape
scrollbarright = 20
img = img[:, :-scrollbarright]
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = 255*(gray < 128).astype(np.uint8)
coords = cv2.findNonZero(gray)
x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(coords)
print("I am ",x,y,w,h)

remaining_height_bottom = ori_h - (y + h)
remaining_width_right_side = ori_w - (x + w)

print("Upper Height, Right Width-->", y, x)
print("Bottom Height, Left Width-->", remaining_height_bottom, remaining_width_right_side)
print("Image Height, Image Width-->", h, w)
print("Original Image Height,Original Image Width-->", ori_h, ori_w)
```